# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync - DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler *not firing*

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm trying to fire a DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler event when my webclient finishes a downloadfileasync call.  I have everything synced up via the online examples on the MS site.  My progress bar works, but the end download event never fires.  Please see the links below for more help.

All relevant C# code can be found at this link: http://pastebin.com/VJ9riPSw
My entire project can be downloaded at this link: https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_30726049375

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The box.com files are actually here: https://app.box.com/s/8s3zltil09u3otcux5192gwostun7imf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation for `WebClient.DownloadDataCompleted Event` says https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted(v=vs.90).aspx:

> This event is raised each time an asynchronous data download operation
>   completes. Asynchronous data downloads are started by calling the
>   **DownloadDataAsync** methods.

But you are using `DownloadFileAsync`, not `DownloadDataAsync`, so instead of `DownloadDataCompleted` event it will raise `DownloadFileCompleted` event.
So you either use `DownloadDataAsync` or add `webClient.DownloadFileCompleted` handler.